# Cloud-init datasource setting timeout doesn't work

Tags: amazon-ec2, timeout, packer, cloud-init

I tried to setting up cloud-init so it waits less time if fails to fetch the meta-data. It would be usefull for validating when instance is created with packer. Then provisioner can change back the timeout.

```
[  134.162079] cloud-init[475]: 2016-12-05 12:33:22,851 - DataSourceEc2.py[CRITICAL]: Giving up on md from ['http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id'] after 120 seconds
```

I used the example from here */usr/share/doc/cloud-init/examples/cloud-config-datasources.txt*

and applied at the end of /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg

```
datasource:
  Ec2:
    timeout: 5
    max_wait: 10
```

But it simply doesn't work, the timeout is still 50s and max_wait 120s.
My OS Red Hat 6, cloud-init Version: 0.7.4

EDIT:

attached 
[cloud.cfg](http://pastebin.com/nREYWNi0)
[cloud-init.log](http://pastebin.com/Ticy5D3A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few trials, it appeared that I need to explicitly specify *datasource_list*. Like in example:

```
datasource_list: [ Ec2, None ]
```

Then the options *timeout* and *max_wait* applied for Ec2 are working.

You can put them under */etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-datasource.cfg*.